# Want to Remove Html tags from string and add next line on closing tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html I want to get text from html. but also want next line where closing tag in html 
My Html

```
<ul><li>There were 1 candidates in the import file</li><li>1 candidates failed<ul><li>1 candidates were missing required fields</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I want Result:-

There were 1 candidates in the import file

1 candidates failed 1 candidates were missing required fields

Means after first line there is closing tag so want next line over there

or Any way to replace start tags with space and replace end tags with dots.
Something like this :-

There were 1 candidates in the import file.1 candidates failed.1 candidates were missing required fields

Comment: `I have html` .. Okay, is your HTML in a string in JS? If yes, do you want to remove all tags to get the text and separate them by a line return? If yes, in a table? You need to put more information, also put what you've tried to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes my html in string in JS and want to remove all html tags and get text and separate them by a line return where closing tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("ul#list > li");
[].forEach.call(items, (item) => console.log(item.innerText));
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>There were 1 candidates in the import file</li>
  <li>1 candidates failed
    <ul>
      <li>1 candidates were missing required fields</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get each list item and then add it's text value to a resulting variable `res` by using the `.each` method:

```js
let result = "";
$('ul li').each((_, elem) => {
  result += $(elem).text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, '') + '\n';
})

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>There were 1 candidates in the import file</li>
  <li>1 candidates failed
    <ul>
      <li>1 candidates were missing required fields</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here I also used some regex to remove any whitespace retrieved from `.text()`

Comment: Actually it is just sample html so there can be any tag like <div> <span> so I want to remove all html tags and on every ending tag want next line @Nick Parsons

Comment: What if you've got `<div><span>h</span><span>e</span><span>l</span><span>l</span><span>o</span></div>`. Do you want each letter of "hello" on a separate line? @Anshul.

Comment: Yes I want each letter on separate  line Actually i am exporting text in excel sheet so in column I want different different  lines not words

Comment: @Anshul if you want to do this with `div`s and `span`s then use `$("div span")` as the selector instead

Comment: there may be any tag div span ul li p br table tr etc. I want to remove all html tags and their closing like </div> </span> </ul> etc replacing with new line

Answer (score 0):

The following accomplishes the desired layout without removing the tag(s), although some tweaking may be involved in a live use-case with cascade in a larger document.

Using CSS, setting the second `li` as `display: inline-flex` and removing the bullet from the embedded `ul` (as well as subjectively removing some padding to line things up nicely).

```css
li:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline-flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul ul {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
      <li>There were 1 candidates in the import file</li>
      <li>1 candidates failed
        <ul>
           <li>1 candidates were missing required fields</li>      
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```